# Cannot exchange method implementations objectForKey of NSDictionary at runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, nsdictionary

I try exchange implementations if objectForKey: of NSDictionary at runtime, but nothing changes!

```
#import "NSDictionary+Utils.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSDictionary (Utils)

+ (void)load
{
    method_exchangeImplementations(class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(objectForKey:)),
                                   class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(_objectForKey:)));
}

- (id)_objectForKey:(id)aKey
{
    NSLog(@"ok");
    id obj = [self _objectForKey:aKey];
    if ([obj isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return obj;
}

@end
```

Who can tell me why?

Thanks for read my poor English.

Comment: Because you're doing something you shouldn't do.

Comment: What you should do is not muck with the function of a class that is used by the entire system.  There is no justifiable reason for needing the above change in behavior (and lots of reasons to not have that behavior).

Answer (score 6):

NSDictionary is a class cluster. You never deal with a direct instance of NSDictionary; instead, dictionaries are always instances of some NSDictionary subclass. So you're swapping a method that you'll never call anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'll use replacement methods such as objForKey: instead... Do you have any something else?

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to achieve I would suggest to use a category on NSDictionary, providing a custom `saveObjectAtIndex:`method and use that in your code.

An other option would be a category on NSNull so it behaves like nil like this: https://gist.github.com/ronaldmannak/4532707

Comment: Even with a category like that, there is still an important difference: NSNull is true while nil is false.

Comment: @robert: I just want avoid [NSNull null] value return from NSDictionary.
I don't want change anything of NSNull, it cause other issues.
Thanks for help!

Comment: @zendo - What issues??